# Is there a way to transfer phone numbers from within Twilio?

Tags: twilio

I'm trying to move the phone numbers in my master account to my subaccounts from within my Twilio dashboard.  Is that possible?  I've seen code for this using PHP or Python, but I don't have a software program to use this solution.  We just work from within Twilio for this service.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can not transfer phone numbers within Twilio dashboard.

Using [cURL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) you can do it from a command line.
Check my answer here: [How to transfer phone number from master account to subaccount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327200/how-to-transfer-phone-number-from-master-account-to-subaccount/37901400#37901400)

As an alternative, you could use Twilio CLI.
Check the examples here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/twilio-cli/examples#transfer-a-phone-number-between-accounts

Comment: Thank you for this! Much appreciated!